# sip.xml : How to make two sip servlet run on the same web application

Tags: xml, servlets, sip, sip-server

I'm driving a bit crazy because i'm trying to make  a different version of the restcomm app click to call and I can not find a way to make two different servlets running on the server(Tomcat 8 telestax version). Specifically I wuold like to use SipRegister as the registration servlet e let the other one make the other work. 
Anyway this is the sip.xml i'm trying to modify. I have already tried with servlet-mapping without succes. Any suggestion?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sip-app>
    <app-name>at.project.servlet.sip.SimpleApplication</app-name>
    <display-name>Sip Servlet App </display-name>
    <description>Third Party Call Control</description>
    <servlet-selection>
        <main-servlet> SipRegister</main-servlet>
    </servlet-selection>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SimpleSipServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>SimpleSipServlet</display-name>
        <description>Simple SIP servlet</description>
        <servlet-class>
            at.project.servlet.sip.SimpleSipServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SipRegister</servlet-name>
        <display-name>SipRegister</display-name>
        <description>Registration Servlet</description>
        <servlet-class>
            at.project.servlet.sip.SipRegister
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            at.project.servlet.sip.SimpleSipServlet
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</sip-app>
```